# DateTime comparison not including the most recent date

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison

I'm trying to understand why the following function doesn't work.

```
public IEnumerable<LogFile> GetLogs(string directory, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    return di.GetFiles("*debug.log").Where(f => f.LastWriteTime > start && f.LastWriteTime <= end).Select(f => new LogFile(f.FullName));
}
```

Why does the second comparison `(f.LastWriteTime <= end)` omit the specified end date?

The first comparison `(f.LastWriteTime > start)` does include the specified start date.

For exampled, if I set the start date to 1/4/2013 and the end date to 1/8/2013 the function return files with the following dates:

1/4/2013,
1/5/2013,
1/6/2013,
1/7/2013

It will not include 1/8/2013, despite the use of <= in the code.

Comment: If you want to include the entire end date you can add a day and then use the `Date` property(midnight): `< end.AddDays(1).Date)`

Comment: As an aside, if you are using .NET 4.0+, you will probably want to use [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles.aspx) instead of using GetFiles

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is what I was originally doing. It seemed to work just fine, but I was more curious as to why it wasn't working as expected. I thought my logic was correct, but I ended up fixing it by using the Date property of the DateTime objects. So my comparison statement now looks like: f.LastWriteTime.Date >= start.Date && f.LastWriteTime.Date <= end.Date

Comment: But that is a different result. Now you exclude the end date from your result. If you would add a day first and use the `Date` property after you'd include the end-day.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It seems to pull the files correctly. I'm not concerned with the time of the file. Just the date. I just need any file modified between, and including, those dates. So if I specified 1/4/2013 to 1/8/2013 I just care about any files modified on 1/8/2013 regardless of the time it was modified.

Comment: @dpCode: Yes, but if there's a file with `LastWriteTime` say `1/8/2013 00:00:01` as end it won't be included because `1/8/2013` is actually `1/8/2013 00:00:00`. That's why i've said that you should add a day and use then the `Date` property. That would result in `1/9/2013 00:00:00` which includes `1/8/2013 00:00:01`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're dealing with date & time values, not just date values.

`1/6/2013 4:30` is not equal to `1/6/2013 12:00`, despite the fact that the dates are the same.

You can use the `Date` property on each of the `DateTime` objects to get new `DateTime` objects where the time is always midnight.

Comment: Yup! Seems to do the trick. Have my code as follows now:
'f.LastWriteTime.Date >= start.Date && f.LastWriteTime.Date <= end.Date'

I could have sworn I've tried that at one point, but I could be wrong! Thanks!

Comment: Servy is right, if the time is not specified for a DateTime object it is assumed to be midnight, which is considered the beginning of the day not the end. For your code to act as expected, you need to set the time portion of end to 23:59:59 or ignore the time altogether.

Comment: @Kevin And even then, times have a smaller precision than one second, so it's much easier to say less than midnight of the next day to avoid such issues.  In terms of readability though, if you only care about dates I'd take the time to call `.Date` on all of the relevant dates; it's clearer to the reader.

Comment: @Servy Agreed, but I didn't want to try to go into how to calculate what the last tick value for a date would be. But you are correct that using my suggestion any files created in the final second of the date would still be missed. Ignoring the time altogether (which is what comparing the Date portion in your suggestion does) is indeed the most accurate and inclusive method.

Comment: Not concerned with the exact times of the files. Just need to get all files modified between, and including, the specified date.

Answer (score 4):

DateTime contains (as its name implies) also time component. So your comparison actually is:

```
f.LastWriteTime > start && f.LastWriteTime <= end

f.LastWriteTime > 1/4/2013 00:00:00 && f.LastWriteTime <= 1/8/2013 00:00:00
```

The last file date is probably something like 1/8/2013 13:45:12 so

```
1/8/2013 13:45:12 <= 1/8/2013 00:00:00
```

is false.
Because of the time component the first date acctualy is included in result:

```
1/4/2013 00:00:00 > 1/4/2013 13:45:12
```

is true.

Answer (score 0):

But when compare with date plue time, the last second of value is not included: time <= 1/14/2013 1:26:42 am, it include 1/14/2013 1:26:41 AM ?